# Update Field Manager fields dynamically based on ObjectChoiceField selectedIndex

Tags: java, blackberry

I have an ObjectChoiceField and I have a VerticalFieldManager (VFM) with a couple of LabelFields and EditFields.

I want to update the fields in the VFM dynamically based on the selectedIndex of the ObjectChoiceField.

I already trap the user choice via a fieldChangeNotify, but I am not sure of the best strategy to update the VFM.

Is my only option to delete the all the fields, and create new instances on each field change?

P.S.  I am going for a filter effect, so one option will show all records, but another will only show a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer:
[ObjectChoiceField in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218206/objectchoicefield-in-blackberry/3231732#3231732)

As suggested in answer, use fieldChanged() instead of fieldChangedNotify() method.

Comment: Thanks.  I dont think my problem is with the ObjectChoiceField.  I am using that exactly how I want.  Its the updating of the VFM that I want to figure out

Comment: Since you just want to update LabelField and EditField content in VFM, you can use setText method to change content. And if you want to replace whole field, you can use Manager.replace().